# Invalid hook call expo

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, expo

I am creating a monorepo to store both the web app and expo app for a project. I have setup using https://github.com/altick/cra-expo-monorepo . I have created a shared folder to store the common code.
I am facing an issue importing a react component which uses a hook into the expo app, it gives the following error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I also faced the same issue in the react web app, I found out it was due to multiple react copies( both in the app and the shared one) but I was able to solve it by updated the webpack config to use the apps react through webpack alias. However, I dont know how to achieve the same with expo.

An example component

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

export const Dummy = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("Test");
    return <>{data}</>
}
```

I want to know how can I solve this issue

Comment: Please show the component.

Comment: Well the issue is with any component that uses a hook ( even useState )

Answer (score 0):

You can't use React hook outside of main function. I am pretty sure you put const Dummy() function outside the main function.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

export const Dummy = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("Test");
    return <>{data}</>
}

export default function SomeMainFunction() {
  ...
}
```

please change above function as below.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

export default function SomeMainFunction() {

  export const Dummy = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("Test");
    return <>{data}</>
  }

   ...
}
```